# What happens if my Anderson Darling score is more than 10?

Tags: probability, distributions

I am using crystal ball to fit a distribution curves. Based on the fitting, the AD score is 20, p value is 0. What does it mean? Does it mean it is suitable?

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With an exceptionally high AD score of 20, and a p value that is probably equal to 0.0000% you can reject the null hypothesis that your data may have a distribution that could come from the same population as the distribution you are testing for.

I suspect you used the AD test to check if your data is normally distributed.  It is not.  For it to have a viable probability that it would be normally distributed (not being able to reject the null hypothesis that it is normally distributed, your AD score should be typically much less than 1.00.

Comment: Hi Sympa! Thanks for the reply! But would like to understand what is the typical range of acceptance for AD test (does it mean the lower the better?) I have distribution profiles such as Gamma, Beta curves. Any rule of thumb? :)

Comment: With such tests, it is all about the resulting p-value.  If the p-value is really low you reject the null hypothesis that the distribution of your data is similar to the statistical distribution you compare your data to.  Typically, people use a p-value of 0.10 or lower as a threshold that you can reject the null hypothesis that your data distribution is the same as the distribution you compare it to.